# openCV recognition throws exception (LBPH algorithm)

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, lbph-algorithm

I tried to detect and recognize face through LBPH algorithm. For that, I tried the following example:

[Mastering OpenCV Chapter 8 FaceRecognition](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/blob/master/Chapter8_FaceRecognition/)

The code runs and works successfully for **Eignefaces** and **Fisherfaces** but gives an exception when recognize for **LBPH algorithm**. I can't figure it out. The exception is:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (no parameter 'eigenvectors' is found)  in unknown function, file "..\modules\core\src\algorithm.cpp" line 882.
```

In line 882,

```
CV_Error_( CV_StsBadArg, ("No parameter '%s' is found", parameter ? parameter : "<NULL>") );
```

The above line is called after the following line which causes the exception

```
Mat eigenvectors = model->get<Mat>("eigenvectors");
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Please experts come and rescue me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the same question in [OpenCV Forum](http://answers.opencv.org/question/25564/opencv-recognition-throws-exception-lbph-algorithm/), I learned that the problem is in my sample code. Some portions are not applicable for **LBPH Algorithm**. The lines are below:

```
Mat reconstructedFace;
reconstructedFace = reconstructFace(model, preprocessedFace);
if (m_debug)
    if (reconstructedFace.data)
        imshow("reconstructedFace", reconstructedFace);

// Verify whether the reconstructed face looks like the preprocessed face, otherwise it is probably an unknown person.
double similarity = getSimilarity(preprocessedFace, reconstructedFace);
```

The above lines of code are applicable for Eigenfaces and Fisherfaces which I don't know! After **commenting** those lines of code, I simply call

```
identity = model->predict(preprocessedFace);
```

which gives the prediction result and hence.

Answer (score 0):

How you define yout algorithm?

If you want to detect face, you have to define model in this way:

```
const char* recAlgorithmEigenfaces = "FaceRecognizer.Eigenfaces";
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model;
model = Algorithm::create<FaceRecognizer>(recAlgorithmEigenfaces);
```

Optionally you have to check the model:

```
if (model.empty()) {
 /* throw exception */ 
}
```

And then train your model..

## edit

another explanation, reading [here](http://books.google.it/books?id=UjWoIFHcr58C&pg=PT434&lpg=PT434&dq=%22FaceRecognizer.Eigenfaces%22&source=bl&ots=S8k6AArx-A&sig=Q4qttbQVYDQNi_VTSSSXzdbl5B0&hl=it&sa=X&ei=fnywUrXRE8jNygOR8oGoDg&ved=0CEwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22FaceRecognizer.Eigenfaces%22FaceRecognizer.Eigenfaces&f=false), is that:

> [..]face recognition algorithms are available through the
>   **FaceRecognizer** class in OpenCV's **contrib** module. Due to dynamic linking, it is possible that your program is linked to the
>   contrib module but it is not actually loaded at runtinme (if it was
>   deemed as not required). So it's recommended to call the

```
cv::initModule_contrib()
```

> function before trying to access the FaceRecognizer algorithms.    The
>   function is only available from OpenCV v2.4.1, so it also ensures that
>   the face recognition algorithms are at least available to you at
>   compile time [..]

Comment: Yes, I do the exactly as you said. The difference is I wrote `FaceRecognizer.LBPH`.

Comment: are you sure that file exist? try to give the full-absolute path (eg: /home/test/opencv/FaceRecognizer.Eigenfaces)

Comment: Actually, the `train()` portion is okay for me. The problem is when the code try to reconstruct a face by using `model` and `preprocessedFace` in the function `Mat reconstructFace(const Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model, const Mat preprocessedFace)`

Comment: There is no such file in that directory! But there is no such file named `FaceRecognizer.Eigenfaces` too but it's working. I am really confused here. Is there should be any such file there? please give me some links so that I can clear about it. Thanks

Comment: look at edit... maybe you need to update your opencv version (at least 2.4.1)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. My version is 2.4.7 I solved the problem from openCV forum.